# ¿Cómo utilizar argumentos de un comando anterior en Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, parámetros, línea-de-comandos

A veces ocurre que generas un fichero y automáticamente quieres cambiarle permisos:

```
touch fichero
chmod +x fichero
```

Es decir, quieres realizar una misma acción sobre un parámetro. Es un poco rollo escribir el parámetro dos veces, por lo que con frecuencia uso `!?` para referirme al último parámetro antes utilizado:

```
touch fichero
chmod +x !$
```

Sin embargo, esto solamente me funciona para recuperar el último parámetro. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo con el resto?

Por ejemplo, dado este comando, ¿cómo puedo conseguir el segundo parámetro?

```
$ echo "1: hola" "2: ¿cómo estás?" "3: yo bien"
1: hola 2: ¿cómo estás? 3: yo bien
```

Comment: Más información, bastante extensa, en [How To Use Bash History Commands and Expansions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bash-history-commands-and-expansions-on-a-linux-vps)

Comment: @Arie ¿me podrías justificar la [supresión de etiquetas](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/58487/revisions) que hiciste a la pregunta? Creo que son apropiadas para la pregunta.

Comment: lo siento. Ambas etiquetas son sinònimos de las que ya estàn, ambas etiquetas solo tienen una ùnica pregunta asociada y no ayudan a la clasificaciòn de la pregunta al no haber mas preguntas con estas etiquetas. Aùn asi si cree que aun deberìan estar, le pido que proponga los sinonimos correspondientes en la ediciòn de etiquetas.

Comment: @Arie faltaría más, gracias por responder. En general, si haces cambios importantes en una publicacíon es interesante que indiques los motivos en la edición o un comentario, para que sea más fácil de entender. Tienes razón, las etiquetas las creé al formular esta pregunta y actualmente no se usan en ninguna otra pregunta. Dado que el sitio está empezando y es una pregunta parecida a otras del sitio inglés que sí utilizan estas etiquetas, las creé porque creo bueno ir "abriendo camino" y definir etiquetas para segmentar correctamente la información. Si en el futuro no se usan, ¡las elimino!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usa la sintaxis `!-1:2` para devolver el 2º parámetro:

## `!-1:n` → devuele el n-ésimo parámetro

```
$ echo 1 2 3
1 2 3
$ echo !-1:2
echo 2
2
```

En general:

## `!-p:n` → devuele el n-ésimo parámetro de hace `p` comandos

```
$ echo 1 2 3
$ echo 4 5 6
$ echo 7 8 9
$ echo $-2:2
echo 5
5
```

## `!^` → devuelve el primer parámetro

Como en todas las expresiones regulares, `^` se refiere al principio. En este caso, al primer parámetro

```
$ echo 1 2 3
1 2 3
$ echo !^
echo 1
1
```

## `!$` → devuelve el último parámetro:

Como en todas las expresiones regulares, `$` se refiere al final. En este caso, al último parámetro.

```
$ echo 1 2 3
1 2 3
$ echo !$
echo 3
3
```

Nótese que se pueden combinar y hacer que se imprima, por ejemplo, el último parámetro de hace tres comandos:

```
$ echo 1 2 3
$ echo 4 5 6
$ echo 7 8 9
```

Ahora:

```
$ echo !-3:$
echo 3
3
```

Todo está definido en el [Manual de Bash, sección Word Designators](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Designators).