# ¿Qué significa el símbolo ! delante de un parámetro en Bash? (O expansiones indirectas en Bash)

Tags: linux, bash

Tengo la expresión:

```
local vector=("${!3}")
```

¿Qué significado tiene el símbolo '!' delante del 3?

Answer (score 3):

El símbolo `!` aquí actúa como forma de definir una variable indirectamente. Técnicamente se le llama expansión indirecta, pues permite expandir una variable de forma no directa, sino utilizando una variable que contiene el nombre de una variable. Es la manera estándar de usar variables cuyo nombre sea variable.

De este modo, al decir `${!3}` está diciendo `$3` directamente. Hay otros casos sin embargo en los que sí tendría utilidad:

```
$ nombre="var1"
$ var1="hola que tal"
$ echo "${nombre}"      # expande al valor de $nombre 
var1
$ echo "${!nombre}"     # expande la variable contenida en el valor de $nombre
hola que tal
```

La definición completa de:

```
local vector=("${!3}")
```

Está definiendo `$vector` como un array con un único elemento, cuyo valor es el contenido en `$3`. Seguramente se usa dentro de un script y `$3` contiene el valor de la tercera variable que se pasó al ejecutarlo.

Puedes leer más al respecto en el capítulo [Shell Parameter Expansion del manual de GNU Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> ```
> ${!prefix*}
>
> ${!prefix@}
> ```
>
> Expands to the names of variables whose names begin with prefix, separated by the first character of the IFS special variable. When ‘@’ is used and the expansion appears within double quotes, each variable name expands to a separate word.

Answer (score 1):

@fedorqui dio una buena respuesta pero yo quiero tomar otra aproximación (que claramente tocará parte de su respuesta).

En la documentación en `bash(1)` en la sección de `Parameter Expansion` se hace la distinción entre tres casos.

### *Indirect expansion*

O como yo también lo veo, una variable que puede variar. Un caso de uso que yo utilicé fue algo similar a esto.

```
#!/bin/bash

VIDA='11111
11112'

AUTOS='21111
21112'

SALUD='31111
31112'

GMM='41111
41112'

declare -a RAMOS=(VIDA AUTOS SALUD GMM)

for ramo in "${RAMOS[@]}"
do
    echo "============="
    echo "Ramo: $ramo"  # Aquí sólo se imprime el nombre de la variable "ramo".
    echo "${!ramo}" #  Aquí se imprime el contenido de la variable
                    #+ cuyo nombre es el valor de la variable "ramo".
done
```

Y su resultado da esto.

```
=============
Ramo: VIDA
11111
11112
=============
Ramo: AUTOS
21111
21112
=============
Ramo: SALUD
31111
31112
=============
Ramo: GMM
41111
41112
```

### Expansión 2

Cuando se usa de la forma `${!prefijo*}` esta expansión causa que todas las variables con el prefijo *prefijo* se muestren separadas con el primer caracter de la variable especial `IFS`. En cambio, cuando se usa con `${!prefijo@}` cada variable se imprime como palabra separada

Es decir.

```
$ OLDIFS="$IFS"  # Guardamos la variable IFS para volver a ella más tarde.
$ variable_uno=uno
$ variable_dos=dos
$ variable_tres=tres
$ IFS="=,/"  # La cambiamos a gusto.
$ echo "${!variable*}"
variable_dos=variable_tres=variable_uno
$ IFS=",/"  # Volvemos a cambiar para que la coma quede al inicio.
$ echo "${!variable*}"
variable_dos,variable_tres,variable_uno
$ echo "${!variable@}"  # Aquí se va a mostrar nombre por nombre, sin problemas con el IFS.
variable_dos variable_tres variable_uno
$ IFS=$OLDIFS # Volvemos a la "normalidad".
$ echo "${!variable*}"
variable_dos variable_tres variable_uno
```

### Expansión 3

Te devuelve los nombre de las claves de un array. Es decir.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a array_normal=(manzana queso)

declare -A array_asociativo=(
    [fruta]=manzana
    [lacteo]=queso
)

echo "----------------------"
echo "Array común."
echo "----------------------"

for i in "${!array_normal[@]}" # Aquí usamos la expansión.
do
    echo Clave: $i
    echo Valor: ${array_normal[$i]}
    echo "============="
done

echo "----------------------"
echo "Array asociativo."
echo "----------------------"

for i in "${!array_asociativo[@]}" # Aquí volvemos a usar la expansión.
do
    echo Clave: $i
    echo Valor: ${array_asociativo[$i]}
    echo "============="
done
```

Cuya salida es.

```
----------------------
Array común.
----------------------
Clave: 0
Valor: manzana
=============
Clave: 1
Valor: queso
=============
----------------------
Array asociativo.
----------------------
Clave: fruta
Valor: manzana
=============
Clave: lacteo
Valor: queso
```

La diferencia entre `${!array[@]}` y `${!array[*]}` es semejante a la expansión anterior, la del caso del prefijo, es la misma situación con la variable `IFS`.

Un caso en el que lo he usado es para hacer un *join* de un caracter como separador de las palabras de un array.

```
$ declare -a array=(valor1 valor2 valor3)
$ echo "$(IFS='|'; echo "${array[*]}")"
valor1|valor2|valor3
```

Answer (score 0):

El signo de exclamación en bash tiene que ver con el cómo se desarrollaron las computadoras y la historia que hay en ellas, ya que en ciertos momentos es necesario ejecutar comandos que previamente ya habiamos ejecutado. Específicamente **!** tiene que ver con el **historial de comandos**. El historial de comandos lo podemos consultar con el comando **history**. Por ejemplo si tuvieramos algo como lo siguiente:

```
$ history
1 tar cvf etc.tar /etc/
2 cp /etc/passwd /backup
3 echo "hola mundo"
```

Podemos ver que nuestra lista empieza con un tar, después un cp y finalmente un echo. El ejecutar **!3** en nuestra terminal resultaría en:

```
hola mundo
```

Lo que hace **!n** es ejecutar el comando número n que se encuentra en nuestro historial. A diferencia de **!-n** que ejecuta un comando del historial empezando desde el último, es decir, "el comando anterior", "dos comandos antes" ... etc.

Comment: en este caso no es esto

Comment: Tienes razón en el hecho de el simplemente escribirlo inicialmente, pero el que pregunta lo hace especificando «delante de un parámetro». Por lo que la aproximación de @fedorqui es la más cercana al caso porque toca al punto.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo Marco. Para esta pregunta en específico la respuesta de @fedorqui es correcta. Creo que lo que yo escribí complementa un poco pero no es lo que Postiga pregunta.

Comment: Eso estaba pensando. Tal vez, no sé, @fedorqui tendría que ilustrarnos en ese caso, podrías poner en tu respuesta algo que la muestre como un complemento que consideras pertinente mencionar.

Comment: Más bien yo pienso que lo que traería más luz a todo esto es que Postinga nos aclare **qué problema intenta resolver** o en **dónde fue que vio ese comando** jaja

Comment: @Marco yo creo que esta respuesta aporta información útil, pero totalmente desconectada de la pregunta. Yo sugeriría que Pak Lei Chong cree una pregunta aparte hablando de este concepto, que yo toqué un poco en [¿Cómo utilizar argumentos de un comando anterior en Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/58487/83). Al fin y al cabo Bash tiene muchos "truquillos" de estos que dependen íntegramente del contexto.